# Need to get glucose level from a device into an android application i am building

Tags: android, bluetooth

Any suggestion for this task would be helpful.
I am working on building an application that would integrate 
activity data,along with blood glucose level. The google fit api helps
me to get the activity data, but based on my research there are wireles glucose monitors out there that send data to their own application. How can i get this data into my application.

Comment: Ask the manufacturer of the glucose monitor.

Comment: I know that few monitors are supporting sync to Apple Health Kit, is it an easier option to build an ios app rather than android app

Comment: if the glucose monitor device manufacturer followed the standard spec from Bluetooth SIG for glucose monitor devices, then any android that supports reading glucose data will work. Best thing is you can experiment using some apps that are available on playstore. if none of them work, then u need to contact the manufacturer and get the spec to read the values.

Comment: Thank you all! Is there a possibility that any device using the standard bluetooth technology can be accessed using the GATT profile.